# Download file from Writable/Readable Dropbox Transform stream

Tags: node.js, stream, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to download PDF file from Dropbox API. It works fine and I get the string but when I forward the `fileBuffered` to a client I get an empty file. What can be an issue?

```
let fileBuffered = '';

let dropboxPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            dropbox(params, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            }).on('data',function(data) {
                fileBuffered += data;
            });
        });
const file = `data:application/pdf;base64, ${Buffer.from(fileBuffered).toString("base64")}`;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "base64");
    res.send(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is simply because fileBuffered is empty by the time it gets downloaded. Node / Javascript is synchronous. You need to put something like this to fix the issue.

```
    let fileBuffered = '';

    let dropboxPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                dropbox(params, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(result);
                    }
                }).on('data',function(data) {
                    fileBuffered += data;
                }).once('end', () => {
                    const file = `data:application/pdf;base64, ${Buffer.from(fileBuffered).toString("base64")}`;
                    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                    res.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "base64");
                    res.send(file);

              });
    });
```

Comment: I made sure that fileBuffered has 136K string before "const file = ...
" and that's exactly the size of the PDF file that I try to download. Anyway I tried you code and got the same result...

Comment: Can you try .on('finish') instead of once('end')?

Comment: Sure... same result. When I open the downloaded PDF file in Notepad it isn't empty. It's size is 136K after downloading to a client. Something is wrong with the PDF format - it get's screwed and Acrobat Reader opens it as an empty file.